# # TODO in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, todo

I had read through a rails book and once found we can add # TODO: and some # stuff in codes, so we can you some rake cmd to look back.

My problems is I can't find where are those "# stuff" and "rake cmd" I google and search around, but can't find and don't know what keywords to search.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use `# TODO`, `# FIXME`, and `# OPTIMIZE` and you can easily get all of these with the following rake task: `rake notes`

In addition to the default annotations, you can always specify and search for your own annotations:

```
rake notes:custom ANNOTATION=ZOMG
```

Answer (score 18):

rake notes:todo

Answer (score 9):

btw, you need to run that command from the root dir of your rails app. Also, you can run:

```
rake -T
```

to get a full list of the tasks in your rails' Rakefile

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -rn "# TODO" .
```

Comment: Will look through every file in project, which may be slow and not useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Print all annotations**

```bash
$ bin/rails notes
```

```
app/models/user.rb:
  * [  110] [TODO] Refactor this 

test/test_helper.rb:
  * [   72] [FIXME] Unable to stub this method in the `sign_in` helper
```

**Print specific annotations (`FIXME`)**

```bash
$ bin/rails notes -a FIXME
```

```
test/test_helper.rb:
  * [ 72] Unable to stub this method in the `sign_in` helper
```